# How to do a 302 redirect in grpc-gateway

Tags: go, grpc-gateway

I use [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) to host an HTTP server out of my proto definitions. It works great overall.

However, for one special endpoint, instead of returning a value back, I want to do a 302 redirect to an image hosted in an s3.

If you want to return an error via grpc-gateway, you can return it like

```
nil, status.Error(codes.Unauthenticated, "Nope")
```

I wonder if there is something similar to do a 302 redirect?

As far as I get from [this page](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/master/runtime/errors.go#L15) it seems unlikely. I hope I overlooked something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no straightforward way. But there's a workaround.

There's no conception in gRPC similar to 302. So simple error code mappings won't work fine.
But you can overwrite a response forwarder per method so that it extracts `redirectURL` from the response and sets the HTTP status code and `Location` header.

Documentation link:
https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/mapping/customizing_your_gateway/#mutate-response-messages-or-set-response-headers

Comment: I am running into the same use-case but how can one extract `redirectURL` from the message? If I do `resp.redirectURL` the compiler tells me that proto.Message does not implement that. Do I have to do some casting first, or similar?

Comment: @Markus any solution to this?

Answer (score 7):

you could also use [WithForwardResponseOption](https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/mapping/customizing_your_gateway/#mutate-response-messages-or-set-response-headers) method which allows you to modify your response and response headers.

here is what I did to set `Location` header in response.

1. Set `Location` header in your GRPC method using metadata. this adds `Grpc-Metadata-Location` header to your response.

```golang
func (s *Server) CreatePayment(ctx context.Context, in *proto.Request) (*proto.Response, error) {
    header := metadata.Pairs("Location", url)
    grpc.SendHeader(ctx, header)
    
    return &proto.Response{}, nil
}
```

2. If `Grpc-Metadata-Location` header exists in your GRPC response headers, Set HTTP `Location` header and status code as well.

```golang
func responseHeaderMatcher(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, resp proto.Message) error {
    headers := w.Header()
    if location, ok := headers["Grpc-Metadata-Location"]; ok {
        w.Header().Set("Location", location[0])
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
    }

    return nil
}
```

3. Set this func as an Option in `NewServeMux`:

```golang
grpcGatewayMux := runtime.NewServeMux(
    runtime.WithForwardResponseOption(responseHeaderMatcher),
)
```

Comment: Your link is dead. I believe this is the new URL: https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/mapping/customizing_your_gateway/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you mentioned, it appears to be simply mapping the [grpc status codes](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/statuscodes.md) directly to their closest http equivalents. It doesn't appear that there are any codes in the spec that really map to an http redirect. Am I correct in assuming you are using the gateway to connect a browser to a grpc service?

My suggestion would be to work redirects into the protocol somehow. What if the response to certain methods was something like:

```
message HelloResponse {
  string reply = 1;
  bool shouldRedirect = 2;
  string redirectURL = 3;
}
```

Then if the receiver could detect that from the response and redirect client-side. A little less magical, but still lets you do the redirect if needed.

Comment: Hi, that's one option, however, my intention is to use this endpoint directly as a part of `<img src="https://host/endpoint" />` without processing on the frontend.

Comment: Then you are probably more limited. All I can think of is modifying the gateway with the feature you want.

Comment: @captncraig can this be not done on grpc server side before forwarding response?

Comment: @UmutBenzer What did you end up doing?

Comment: I ended up implementing our logic on the client side. In one request I get the URL for the image and in the second request, we get the image itself by using the response of the first request.

This was implemented before I learned that such a thing `WithOutgoingHeaderMatcher` existed. I don't know if that would've been worked for me or not.